# Вызов метода класса из другого метода этого же класса

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы

есть код:

```
<script>
    function MyObject(){
        this.func = function(){

        }

        this.test = function(){
            func();
        }
    }

    var my = new MyObject();

    my.test();
</script>
```

в консоли следующее:

> ReferenceError: func is not defined

вопрос: как вызвать метод **func** класса из другого метода **test** этого же класса?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script>
    function MyObject(){
        this.func = function(){

        }

        this.test = function(){
            this.func();
        }
    }

    var my = new MyObject();

    my.test();
</script>
```