# Как вызвать метод экземпляра класса из статического метода этого же класса?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class A {
  launch() {
    let step = this.step++;

    let coords = this.stops[0][step];
    Tutor.moveRect(coords);
    Tutor.next();
  }

  static next() {
    let next = document.querySelectorAll(".next")[0];
    next.addEventListener("click", launch); // *
  }
}
```

Метод next() внутри себя вызывает метод launch() (должен вызывать), но этого не происходит, а я получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: launch is not defined

Пробовал также сделать так?

```
static next() {
  let next = document.querySelectorAll(".next")[0];
  next.addEventListener("click", function() {
    launch();
  });
}
```

Но это не работает.

И еще пробовал так:

```
class A {
  static launch() {
    let step = this.step++;

    let coords = this.stops[0][step];
    Tutor.moveRect(coords);
    Tutor.next();
  }

  static next() {
    let next = document.querySelectorAll(".next")[0];
    next.addEventListener("click", function() {
      A.launch();
    });
  }
}
```

Но это мне не подходит.

Как обойти такое поведение?

---

О возможных дубликатах.

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520494/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0), например, используется другой синтаксис. Так что ответ на тот вопрос мне не подходит.

Comment: Из статического метода вы можете вызвать только **статический метод** (ваш последний пример). Если хотите вызывать метод экземпляра -- вам нужен собственно экземпляр класса. Если это вам не подходит (уж не знаю почему) - у вас проблемы с архитектурой приложения. ООП тут не при чем

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, дело в том, что метод launch() используется для запуска приложения, соответственно запускается с экземпляра объекта и по своей логике не может быть статическим. Но спасибо за наводку, думаю, стоит это написать в ответ, потому что это и является ответом.

Comment: @smellyshovel ну так и создавайте новый объект `(new A()).launch()`